# Remove Item from Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I'm trying to understand how to remove an item from my Firebase. I've set up a function (`createProvider`) to create an item , but can't figure out how to go about removing an item.

**HTML**

```
<form role="form" name="createProviderForm">
    <input type="text" ng-model="title">
    <button type="submit" ng-click="createProvider()">Submit</button>
</form>

<div ng-repeat="provider in providers">
    <h3>{{ provider.title }}</h3>
    <button type="button" ng-click="removeProvider()">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var rootRef = new Firebase(FBURL);
var providersRef = rootRef.child('providers');

$scope.newProvider = {};
$scope.providers = [];

providersRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  $timeout(function() {
    var snapshotVal = snapshot.val();
    console.log(snapshotVal);
    $scope.providers.push({
      title: snapshotVal.title
    });
  });
});

$scope.createProvider = function() {
  var newProvider = {
    title: $scope.title
  };
  providersRef.push(newProvider);
};

$scope.removeProvider = function() {

};
```

I've got as far as creating a function called `removeProvider` but can't work out what to put inside it. I realise I've got to somehow target the particular item and then remove it from the list. I'm just not sure how.

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use [`$firebase $asArray`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove an item from Firebase, you will need to know its `name()`, which is automatically generated for you when you call `push()` to add a new item to Firebase.

So you will need to bind the name to the scope:

```
$scope.providers.push({
  name: snapshot.name(),
  title: snapshotVal.title
});
```

You then pass this name into your call to `removeProvider` from your HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="provider in providers">
    <h3>{{ provider.title }}</h3>
    <button type="button" ng-click="removeProvider(provider.name)">Remove</button>
</div>
```

And use it to call `remove` on Firebase:

```
$scope.removeProvider = function(name) {
  providersRef.child(name).remove();
};
```

As @SharpieOne already commented, this and many other things are automatically handled for you if you use the AngularFire library (and in this case specifically its `$asArray()` method).

Comment: I've tried the above, but I'm getting this error: `Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"`. I've got AngularFire loaded, so I might try and do it that way. Are there any benefits to using AngularFire to do this?

Comment: Did you check what the value of `name` is in `removeProvider`? The code in my answer is meant to answer your question "how can I delete a Firebase item in my Angular application?". Some debugging effort on your part is expected.

Comment: Sorry, I was having a bit of a mare then. Managed to work out the problem by logging the `providersRef.child(name)` to the console to make sure it was targeting the correct item. In regards to the AngularFire method, are there any reasons/benefits why you would go down that route instead of the one listed in your answer above?

Comment: There are benefits to both approaches: the good folks at Firebase created AngularFire for good reasons, but on the other hand I (personal opinion ahead) sometimes feel it is more complex than using the Firebase Web/JavaScript API directly. You'll have to decide for yourself, after thoroughly studying https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html.

Answer (score 0):

By setting the object value null ypu can remove it .Try the below code

```
$scope.removeProvider = function() {
      var newProvider = {
        title: null
      };
     providersRef.push(newProvider);

    };
```

Comment: That will not work. This code resolves to `providersRef.push().set({ title: null})`, which will simply create a new provider that it then removes.