# Edit Item from Firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firebase

This is sort of a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878682/remove-item-from-firebase). I'm trying to figure out how to edit an existing item that is stored in my Firebase. My items are repeated on the page, and each of them have an "Edit" button next to them.

**HTML**

```
<h3>Editing {{ editedProvider.title }}</h3>
<form>
    <input ng-model="editedProvider.title">
    <button type="submit" ng-click="updateProvider()">Submit</button>
</form>

<div ng-repeat="provider in providers">
    <h3>{{ provider.title }}</h3>
    <button type="button" ng-click="setEditedProvider()">Edit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how I'm currently adding an item to my list:

**JS**

```
var rootRef = new Firebase(FBURL);
var providersRef = rootRef.child('providers');

$scope.newProvider = {};
$scope.providers = [];

providersRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  $timeout(function() {
    var snapshotVal = snapshot.val();
    console.log(snapshotVal);
    $scope.providers.push({
      title: snapshotVal.title,
      name: snapshot.name()
    });
  });
});

$scope.createProvider = function() {
  var newProvider = {
    title: $scope.title
  };
  providersRef.push(newProvider);
};
```

I've then created a function `setEditedProvider` and binded it to the edit button, that when clicked brings up the edit form for that particular item. When I've made my changes however, I need to run a function called `updateProvider`, and I'm having problems creating that function.

```
$scope.editedProvider = null;

$scope.setEditedProvider = function(provider) {
  $scope.editedProvider = angular.copy(provider);
}

$scope.updateProvider = function(provider) {
  // need to take that edited function and push the updated version inside here
}
```

Can I utilise Firebase's data snapshot for this, like I am for creating the item?

Some of this is finally clicking for me, I think I understand how it needs to be done, I just can't work out how to achieve it.

Any help with this problem is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.updateProvider = function(provider) {
   providersRef.child(provider.$id).update({tile:Provider.title});

}
```