# How to remove an object based on its key UID in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a React component that lists  room's UID (random ID in Firebase), along with `roomName` and `creator`.

[image: list of room and creator]

This is the JSON structure in Firebase:

[image: firebase data structure]

The task is simple, upon clicking `X`, I want it to delete the node (and its child nodes) of whichever key user clicks on. For example, if User clicks the x by second key, `KetjGmLHYrbpX6xt_dd`, Firebase would remove `KetjGmLHYrbpX6xt_dd` **and** `RoomName: Holy Incubator | Creator: Robin`.

```
const dbRef = firebase.initializeApp(config).database().ref().child('rooms');

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      text: '',
      roomName: '',
      creator: '',
      firebaseList: {},
      firebaseValuesArray: [],
      firebaseUIDArray: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    dbRef.on('value', snap => {
      this.setState({
        firebaseList: snap.val(),
        firebaseUIDArray: Object.keys(snap.val())
      }, () => {});
    });
  }
...
//function that's supposed to remove the item
  removeItem(index){
    dbRef.child(index).remove();
  }
...
render(){
  return (
    ...
    <DisplayFirebaseValues removeItem={this.removeItem.bind(this)} firebaseList={this.state.firebaseList} />
...


//on DisplayFirebaseValues.js:

class DisplayFirebaseValues extends React.Component{
  render(){
    const firebaseUID = Object.keys(this.props.firebaseList).map((firebaseItem, index) => {
      return <li key={index}><a href="#" onClick={this.props.removeItem}>X</a> {firebaseItem}</li>
    })
...
```

The idea is to pass down the key (random UID) in `DisplayFirebaseValues.js` so the `removeItem(index)` will get the key to locate that particular Firebase UID, and delete that node. However, when I click X, I got the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "[object Object]". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
```

How can I make it work so user can click `X` and remove that particular data? I tried [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878682/remove-item-from-firebase), but it did not work. I am missing something, but can't tell what.

**PS**: If it helps, I stored the entire `rooms` object in `this.state.firebaseList` and all the keys in `this.state.firebaseUIDArray`

```
firebaseList:  Object {-KeoiS8luCsuKhzc_Eut: Object, -KetjGmLHYrbpX6xt_dd: Object, -Kf99qMofAEvj1ajmPc5: Object}
firebaseUIDArray:  ["-KeoiS8luCsuKhzc_Eut", "-KetjGmLHYrbpX6xt_dd", "-Kf99qMofAEvj1ajmPc5"]
```

Comment: It looks like you aren't passing back the mapped object keys in the bound removeItem function. You can do so like this : `onClick={() => this.props.removeItem(firebaseItem)}`

Comment: Did you ever figure out what you had wrong? I have a similar situation.