# Deleting a record from Firebase by ID

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to delete records from my FireBase DB, based on the record's ID, but the records are not being deleted.
I've read SO posts like [How to delete/remove nodes on Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537720/how-to-delete-remove-nodes-on-firebase), [remove-item-from-firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878682/remove-item-from-firebase) and few more, but I cannot solve my problem.

The database's structure is:

```
my_project  
|  
|-messages  
 |+Kg87....  
 |+Kg9a....  
 |+and so on...
```

My code:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIza....",
    authDomain: ".firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://myProject.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "myproject.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: ""
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
exports.delete =
functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/text')
    .onWrite(event => { 
        var db = firebase.database();
        var ref = db.ref("messages");
        //console.log(ref.child("-Kg9a...").toJSON()); //- OK prints https://myproject.firebaseio.com/messages/Kg9a...
        ref.child("-KgOASNRfF2PheKQ6Yfu").remove();  //Does nothing, returns promise - pending
    });
```

To my understanding `ref` is a reference to the `messages` node, so `ref.child("Kg9a....")` is a reference to the desired child.

- I don't get any error, but nothing happens. The record remains in the DB.
- If I change the last line to `console.log(ref.child("Kg9a....").remove());` I see that the log says  `Promise { <pending> }` but even after few hours nothing happens.
- This is not a security rule issue - I've set my security rules to ".read": true, ".write": true and it still doesn't delete the record.
- My firebase version is `3.5.0` - I've installed `3.7.1`, but when I run `firebase -V` I get that the version is `3.5.0`.
  Any advice?

Comment: Can you please add the actually code you are using? A jsFiddle example would be awesome.

Comment: @adolfosrs - I've added the full code. I'm running it from the firebase's console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few changes to get that working. I assume you really want to delete the record that triggered the event, not the literal string ID in your example. You needed to return the promise you were getting back from remove() though I have found even having a then() handler will work but since returning it is documented as necessary I usually do both. Promises are like result/return codes, usually not to be ignored.

```
var someId = '-KgOASNRfF2PheKQ6Yfu';
exports.delete =
    functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/text')
        .onWrite(event => {
          if (!event.data.exists()) return;
          var ref = event.data.adminRef.root.child('/messages').child(someId);
          return ref.remove().then(function(){
            console.log('OK, gone');
          }).catch(function(e){
            console.log('OOPS, problem: ' + e.message);
          })
        });
```

Comment: No, I want to delete a specific record with the given ID. My final goal is to delete old messages from the DB.

Comment: This onWrite handler will run on every change to any records. How do you know the id of the record you want to delete? You will even get called for the one you are deleting. In any case, just put that id in the 2nd chile() method call. I'll edit the answer to illustrate.

Comment: Well, it works. So the problem was at the way I was trying to get a refernce to my record. I'd like to know why `ref = event.data.adminRef.root.child('/messages').child(someId);` works, while `firebase.database().ref("messages").child(someId);` doesn't.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but in a firebase cloud function, I initialize the admin api with something like: `firebase.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);` but in your case you can use the reference from the event.